# Make gcc print the code line when "required from here" error is printed

Tags: gcc

When my static assertion triggers, I get the following error message:

```
In file included from test2.cpp:1:
test.h: In instantiation of ‘test::test<T, test_from,test_to>::test() [with T = Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 1>; unsigned int test_from = 3740358174u; unsigned int test_to = 837757431u]’:
test2.cpp:51:27:   required from here
test.h:38:9: error: static assertion failed: Wrong number assignment. Numbers in computation are assigned to a different object.
         static_assert(test_from==test_from2,"Wrong number assignment. Numbers in computation are assigned to a different object.");
         ^
```

I would like gcc to print the line and highlight the character for the "required from here" disgnostic:

```
In file included from test2.cpp:1:
test.h: In instantiation of ‘test::test::test() [with T = Eigen::Transform; unsigned int test_from = 3740358174u; unsigned int test_to = 837757431u]’:
test2.cpp:51:27:   required from here
         destination = source.inverse();
                     ^
test.h:38:9: error: static assertion failed: Wrong number assignment. Numbers in computation are assigned to a different object.
         static_assert(test_from==test_from2,"Wrong number assignment. Numbers in computation are assigned to a different object.");
         ^
```

Is there any compiler flag or code pragma I can activate to have this behaviour?